# hibernate annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

iam executing hibernate anotation example in eclipse galileo iam getting the following error.

```
Hibernate: insert into employee1 (Name, ID) values (?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at net.roseindia.Example1.main(Example1.java:22)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'test.employee1' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1566)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Did you actually create a database? < *Table 'test.employee1' doesn't exist*

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'test.employee1' doesn't exist

That means that the table doesn't exist :-) If you want Hibernate to automatically create and drop the tables, set the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create-drop`. Also, I'd recommend reading Hibernate documentation, as it's one of the best sources for beginners.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration